# Proof that references the conclusion of a previous proof in Coq

Tags: coq

assuming I am proving an equivalence relation:

```
P <-> Q
```

and I have managed to proof the implication part:

```
P -> Q
```

but when I try to proof the other direction, that is

```
Q -> P
```

it turns out that I will need to use `P -> Q`. might I ask what's the strategy to organize proof that requires an immediate conclusion made a few lines above?

Comment: That's interesting... Is it possible for you to share your lemma?

Comment: @AntonTrunov nvm. in fact I realized I fell into a complicated argument and I found a much easier argument to get through the proof and it turns out my previous thought was quite stupid.

Comment: That's ok :) My train of thought was like this: suppose one needs a term (let us call it `ptoq`) of type `P -> Q` while proving the other direction, but a non-trivial usage of `ptoq` would be an application to a term (`p`) of type `P` (that corresponds to the modus ponens rule), but to apply `ptoq` to `p` one needs to construct such `p`, which is the overall goal at this stage of proof. From all the above follows that we don't need `ptoq` to prove the other direction.

Comment: @AntonTrunov your reasoning is correct with propositional logic, which is what the question suggests but I've seen examples of this with first-order statements.

Comment: @Zimmi48 Cool! Could you point me to an example?

Comment: @AntonTrunov To prove `∀ a w, a.w.a⁻¹ = 1 -> w = 1` you may use the fact that `∀ a w, w = 1 -> a.w.a⁻¹ = 1` (which is trivial) and apply it to `a⁻¹` and `a.w.a⁻¹` (of course because this is so trivial, you can actually do the proof without resorting to using the reciprocal statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start with an `assert` before splitting the equivalence `P <-> Q`:

```
Goal forall P Q, P <-> Q.
Proof.
intros P Q.
assert (PimpliesQ : P -> Q).
{  admit. (* your proof *)
}
split; [assumption|].
```